# Cascading dropdownlist not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

i tried to change an cascading dropdownlist example http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/jQuery/224_Building_Cascading_DropDownList_in_ASPNet_Using_jQuery_and_JSON.aspx

But i get always the message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"

Maybe someone has an idea?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentplaceholderHEAD" runat="Server">
</script src="~/_scripts/jQuery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Ticket_ArtDropDownList.ClientID %>").change(function() {
            $("#<%=Ticket_StatusSelect.ClientID %>").html("");
            var Ticket_Art = $("#<%=Ticket_ArtDropDownList.ClientID %> > option:selected").attr("value");
            if (Ticket_Art != 0) {
                $.getJSON('Ticketdetails.ashx?Ticket_Art=' + Ticket_Art, function(cities) { //wozu dient dieses "cities" ?
                    $.each(cities, function() {
                        $("#<%=Ticket_StatusSelect.ClientID %>").append($("</option>").val(this['Ticket_Art']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can't tag all my code as "Sourceode" because its not working corectly..

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="Server">
<div>
```

Ticket_ID:
                    Ticket_Art:
                        
                    
                    Ticket_Status:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stands out at me is your script tag...I don't believe jQuery is being included correctly, this:

```
</script src="~/_scripts/jQuery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Should be:

```
<script src="~/_scripts/jQuery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also check your source, make sure the `~/` is being resolved to the correct directory in the final HTML.  Also in your loop, `$("</option>")` should be: `$("<option/>")`.

The last suggestion is you can use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) directly on a `<select>` to get the current value, like this:

```
var Ticket_Art = $("#<%=Ticket_ArtDropDownList.ClientID %>").val();
```

Comment: Hello, the code-tag in my post converts <script> </script> to </script> and the option tag to </option>. But you where right. The path to the jQuery File was wrong. Now i'm not getting the Object inspected Error. But the cascading dropdownlist doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not getting to the script code when i try to use the debugger. Is there something wrong with the event handler?

Comment: Firebug has a Problem with this Line: $("#<%=Ticket_StatusSelect.ClientID %>").append($("<option></option>").val(this['Ticket_Art']).html(this['Text']));

Comment: Ticket_Art must be Ticket_Status

Answer (score 0):

- Path to jQuery File was not correct.
- setting the options was not correct. There was no Ticket_Art but Ticket_Status in the response.